# How to get record from table which contain date field in unix timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am storing my date by using the time() function in PHP. I have a search section in my program.And the field for date is done by jquery datepicker. This is my date format eg: 14/12/2012.

The problem is the filed in table is timestamp. How can i select the actual date from this date string using MySQL query?

I am using codeigniter as framework. Is there any function to do this?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

time() in PHP simply returns a unix time stamp - seconds since Jan 1/1970. MySQL timestamp, date, and datetime fields are NOT directly compatible with that value, but you can convert between the two easily:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourtimestampfield) AS php_compatible_time_value, ...
```

Note that MySQL's date string format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. You cannot use your `dd/mm/yyyy` format unless you convert to MySQL's expected format.

Comment: Thanks Marc B but actually Edga posted what is i need but it makes some issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '14/12/2012';
$d = explode('/',$date);
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $d[1], $d[0], $d[2]);
```

And then you use $timestamp in your query

Of course you're gonna need different approaches for dates in different format UK/US etc. mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: I tried your code when i post date like 30/11/2012 as per your code i got the timestamp like 1354230000 but the time stamp in the database is 1354272207 so it is not matching the time stored in the table. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: remember, timestamps include hours/minutes/seconds. mktime above is using midnight (12:00:00am) as the time, while your DB timestamp is using some other time in the middle of the day.

Comment: Yes i know that can you tell me how can i do this?

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(youttimestampfield))) will return the timestamp without looking at the hour/minutes/seconds (meaning 00:00:00)

Comment: @Arunkumar: a sargable predicate would be of the form:  `WHERE t.mytimestampcol >= '2012-11-30' AND t.mytimestampcol < DATE_ADD('2012-11-30',INTERVAL 1 DAY)`